# What is a homotopy equivalence?

Tags: homotopy-theory

I have found the following problem. Let $A\subseteq X$ be a contractible space. Let $a_0\in A$. Is the embedding $X\setminus A\to X\setminus\{a_0\}$ a homotopy equivalence?

I don't understand the question. I know that two spaces $Y$ and $Z$ are homotopy equivalent when there are such continuous $f:Y\to Z$ and $g:Z\to Y$ that $f\circ g$ is homotopic to $\mathrm{id}_Z$, and $g\circ f$ is homotopic to $\mathrm{id}_Y$. I would think that a homotopy equivalence had to be the pair of functions $f,g$, not just one function. But there is only one function in the problem.

Comment: @ThomasRot OK, thanks. Is there a name for this other function? Like a homotopy inverse or something like this?

Comment: This is precisely the kind of thing that I think the language of category theory helps address quite elegantly. A homotopy equivalence is precisely an isomorphism in a category called the homotopy category (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy_category) in the same way that a group isomorphism is an isomorphism in a category called the category of groups and a homeomorphism is an isomorphism in a category called the category of topological spaces...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question asks if there exists another function with the properties you stated. The [Nlab](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/homotopy+inverse) calls these maps homotopy inverses of one another.